# Special characters in description when creating a new album

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, character-encoding, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a new album using Facebook's Graph API and JavaScript SDK. When creating a new album with a description (message) and name, special characters are being encoded. However, when I try to encode the characters, they don't get decoded once the album is created. Has anyone else come across this issue?

### JavaScript

```
/** Example One: Facebook encodes characters **/
var albumName = "Album Name";
var albumDesc = "Description with áéíóú";
FB.api("/me/albums", "post", {message:albumDesc, name:albumName}, function(res) {
     albumID = res.id;
     uploadPhotoToAlbum(albumID);
});

/** Example Two: Facebook does not decode characters **/
var albumName = "Album Name";
var albumDesc = "Description with %C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA";
FB.api("/me/albums", "post", {message:albumDesc, name:albumName}, function(res) {
     albumID = res.id;
     uploadPhotoToAlbum(albumID);
});

/** Example Three: Facebook does not decode characters **/
var albumName = "Album Name";
var albumDesc = "Description with &#225;&#233;&#237;&#243;&#250;";
FB.api("/me/albums", "post", {message:albumDesc, name:albumName}, function(res) {
     albumID = res.id;
     uploadPhotoToAlbum(albumID);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who may have this issue, I found that it was due to the file encoding. After encoding the file as UTF-8, "Example One" worked as expected.